# JSch addIdentity - How to pass private and public key strings vs. file path

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

There are a lot of examples on this, but none of them show a working example on how use the .ppk public/private file components in a string form converted to a `byte[]` and used with the `JSch.addIdentity(String,byte[],byte[],byte[])` method. Can someone look at the following method and let me know where I'm going wrong. It doesn't like the strings converted to a `byte[]`. The strings are not in full for security reasons, but I think you'll get the point of what I'm trying accomplish with this. Unfortunately, I'm stuck using strings for this since I cannot use the .ppk file directly.

```
public void InitChannelSftp() throws JSchException {
    JSch ssh = new JSch();
    session_ = ssh.getSession(userName_, host_, port_);
    session_.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    
    String passPhrase= "trustNoOne";

    String privateKey= "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
            "hvbytegNktMU05bc3QlCrSs+YHkMAvZRkzcjaXDdcKDfSZyDqcFHfkup1N6CMDg4\n" +
            "yZh0ou+7G8jDQtn29YoAO0tpEW4EGQiI6918iMk22012ytcsCnM80/hj1JbVa4St\n" +
            "1StZKJtBYSu1bRZCpFPygditUGc9pZhDWfgDxLTzQdDMcmdvMb9AgpNKZAz8n0OR\n" +
            "2tuGPAogbt8e48ad9H7IYuikhIqQU42DkrAqRPJDUZqP3gGdzwstuDPl1dwrRaCs\n" +
            "vTynsEMDCjVjNyxRK9sbBO/BwFTaFRM2oN4BvCbfbQKyhRrXZ1gjNMv1P5GxchKj\n"+
            "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

    String publicKey= "-----BEGIN SH2 PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
            "AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEA6wXxLoqF70gkd2hURVlmq+iPCBPmkZ6IwCST\n" +
            "nlxHY/Jc0izbn+6hyFUZmS53LN9CJyjjVvU+UAWapU2tTJKwO6aI8xcKmtBjdDeS\n" +
            "GJgh6C+srGFlbNTXzV8sMmGEQirLyTOMwGviRFOhKn5/bUbqpw==\n" +
            "-----BEGIN SH2 PUBLIC KEY-----\n"


    ssh.addIdentity(
        "Test Conn", privateKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII),
        publicKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII), passPhrase.getBytes());

    session_.connect();
    channel_ = session_.openChannel("sftp");
    channel_.connect();
    ChannelSftp sftp_ = (ChannelSftp) channel_;
}
```

Error:

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@25be7b63

Comment: I met a similar problem of invalid privatekey. Your display of JAVA code of key content assignment did inspire me my wrong of coding. That is the end of line character \r or \r\n must be included in the key content assignment. Then my problem was resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
ssh.addIdentity(
    UUID.randomUUID().toString(), privateKey.getBytes(charset),
    publicKey.getBytes(charset), passPhrase.getBytes(charset));
```

The following private key format works:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,322A25B18A52EDD1

Pwb2h8N...x8ijUQ==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

A blank line at the end is not needed.

In PuTTY, this is achieved via *`Conversions > Export OpenSSH key`*.